# Shutdown incomplete when the lid is closed after pressing shutdown

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, shutdown

I press shutdown button and if the lid is closed before the shutdown process end, this one resumes after I reopen the lid

Comment: Have you considered reporting this as a bug ?

Comment: @NGRhodes I don't know where can I report this as a bug

Comment: Here http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem here on Ubuntu 13.10.
I solved it by adding the line :

```
    HandleLidSwitch=lock
```

in the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

And then using this command to make the changes effective:

```
    sudo restart systemd-logind
```

I hope it solves your problem too. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, could you elaborate on what your suggested change does? It sounds like you replace Suspend behavior by lock behaviour? but wouldn't that prevent the laptop from suspending when you actually want it to suspend by closing the lid?